# eclipse aws sdk for java "temporarily moved"

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I've installed the AWS for Eclipse plugin. The install goes well and I'm able to use the AWS explorer in Eclipse. But, it's impossible to create an AWS java project. I get this error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The "moved temporarily" error is very perplexing.

[image]